# Count the number of false booleans per month in a list of dates?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list such as the following, which contains booleans for each date over several months. I would like to determine the number of False booleans in each month with the ultimate goal of determining a monthly "False" percentage for each month. For example, if November had 15 days that were False, I would like to show 50% for November. How could this be done in Python?

```
list = [('2015-11-01', False), ('2015-11-02', True), ('2015-11-03', True), ('2015-11-04', True), ('2015-11-05', True)]
```

Comment: Show us your coding effort please?

Answer (score 2):

Store the data in a dict using the year as the outer key to group by year and in each year count the number of times you see False:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(float))

from calendar import monthrange, month_name
for k, v in lst:
    year, mth, _ = k.split("-")
    d[int(year)][int(mth)] += not v

for year, dct in d.items():
    for mn, v in dct.items():
        _,  days = monthrange(year, mn)
        print("Average for {}-{} is {}".format(year, month_name[mn], v / days))
```

Once you have the count you can use the correct amount of days per month for the particular year to calculate the percentage. Not every year has the same amount of days per month so you cannot use a generic calendar to test against or ignore the year, the calendar module handles the days for us.

Creating some random data:

```
from  random import choice

lst = [('2015-09-{}'.format(i), choice((True, False))) for i  in range(1,31)] + [('2015-11-{}'.format(i), choice((True, False))) for i  in range(1,31)]
```

Outputs:

```
Average for 2015-September is 0.533333333333
Average for 2015-November is 0.6
```

If the year is always the current year then you can simplify creating the dict to:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
for k, v in lst:
    year, mth,_= k.split("-")
    d[mth] += not v

print(d)
```

But just make sure again you compare the amount of days correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This statement will return a list of length 12, containing the number of True values for each respective month, of the variable "list":

```
[sum([1 if int(pair[0][5:7]) == n and pair[1] else 0 for pair in list]) for n in range(1, 13)]
```

By removing the and statement, this statement will return the total number of entries for each month as a list

```
[sum([1 if int(pair[0][5:7]) == n else 0 for pair in list]) for n in range(1, 13)]
```

By combining the two previous statements, we can get a list of percentages as such:

```
trues = [sum([1 if int(pair[0][5:7]) == n and pair[1] else 0 for pair in list]) for n in range(1, 13)]
total = [sum([1 if int(pair[0][5:7]) == n else 0 for pair in list]) for n in range(1, 13)]
percentages = [trues[n] / float(total[n]) * 100 if total[n] != 0 else None for n in range(12)]
```

In which if a month has 0 entries it will return None

-EDIT-

I interpreted this as seeing what percentage of all the values entered for a certain month are True, but if you're looking for the percentages of all the days in the month that have a value marked True, simply change the total variable to:

```
total = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
```

(assuming a non-leap year)